# The right way to use python in web development

Tags: python, server-side

What is the right way to use a server-side language to create a website? Do I have to write every webpage in python (print "" etc.) or should I use the server-side just when i want to access a database,for example, and than format the output via javascript?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: at first you can try `wsgi module` and after smth of python based web frameworks(`django` etc)

Comment: look up a framework like django: https://www.djangoproject.com/ . In 99% of the cases, you won't be doing any low-level stuff.

Comment: Look at [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org) for serving pages and [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org) for templating data into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two things to consider, when chosing what to do on the server side:

**1. Security:** Anything you send to the client side will be accessible to the receiver as plain text (the javascript too). Only send data once you're certain about the clients identity (i.e. logged in). Therefore, anything security sensitive should happen on the server side.

**2. Processing time v.s. network load:** If a lot of users are doing a lot of different calculations with a data set (i.e. sorting, summarizing, sub-totalling etc.), the server CPU can be offloaded by sending raw data (granted pt. 1 is taken care of), and let each client handle the calculations. On the other hand, this might cause a lot of users to request too much data, which can degrade network performance.

As a consequence: If uncertain, do as much as possible on the server side. If not uncertain, the question is void:-)

As for the other part of your question, regarding how to generate the HTML: consider using a web-framework like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). This will give you an abstraction layer, which yields much functionality pr. line of code. Of course, this way a lot of stuff happens "behind the scenes", which gives you less direct control, but usually the benefits outweigh the disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to use Python as web language. You could just use it via cgi interface or you could use more elaborate frameworks like Django to do it.

There is no right or wrong in that decision - just a measure if it adequate to your problem.

If you are brand new to the topic, I would urge you to have a look an Django - as it may guide you somewhat to not only solve your problems, but do it elegantly.

Comment: Nah, using the CGI interface in 2012 is actually fairly wrong. At least use a WSGI microframework; you'll hate your self a lot less.

Comment: I agree. Most of the frameworks will not only make thing s easier - some of the also support you to write code that does not contain obvious security problems.